# how to get vertices in mxGraph javascript

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I'm trying to add a new icon in my existing vertex/vertices programmatically using `mxCellOverlay` and `addCellOverlay`. How do I get all my vertices I have in my workeditor xml so I can pass it in `addCellOverlay` parameter, like the example below.

```
var overlay = new mxCellOverlay(new mxImage('editors/images/overlays/check.png',
16, 16), 'Overlay tooltip');
graph.addCellOverlay(allMyVertices, overlay);
```

reference: http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/fixedicon.html

If I add this code in the fixedIcon.html (line 72) afer `var v1` it gives me a new tick/check icon.

```
var overlay = new mxCellOverlay(new mxImage('editors/images/overlays/check.png',
16, 16), 'Overlay tooltip');

graph.addCellOverlay(v1, overlay);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to get the vertices (not edges) of one level, I would suggest `mxGraph.getChildVertices` instead of `mxgraph.getCells`. But you have to pass the parent mxCell to the function. You will then get all child vertices of this cell. E. g. if you want to add an overlay to all vertices of the default parent you could do something like this:

```
var overlay = new mxCellOverlay(new mxImage('editors/images/overlays/check.png', 16, 16), 'Overlay tooltip');
var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
var vertices = graph.getChildVertices(parent);
graph.addCellOverlay(vertices, overlay);
```

Of course, a recursive implementation would be possible, if you want all vertices of every level.

For further informations:
https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.getChildVertices

Answer (score 0):

Here is :

```
mxGraph.prototype.getCells = function(x,y,width,height,parent,result);
```

Comment: Try to add a short explanation along with your code. Code only answers are usually seen as low quality answers.